# Can a single model "belong_to" more than one parent model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationships

Just as on StackOverflow, in my app a User can write Questions and can also provide Answers:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  belongs_to :user
end


class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
end
```

My question has to do with the Answer model above:

**Is it ok for an `Answer` to `belong_to` both the User and the Question models?**

I have a feeling I read somewhere that a model can only have a single foreign key. If so, how do I rectify that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly ok and you will have many models that have many belongs_to as your domain model gets more complex.  I don't know where you would have read that a model can only have a single foreign key.

Comment: Many people think that since a Class can only have 1 **parent** that models can only have 1 belongs_to.  A misconception, but actually quite common.